# IE Won't Set Cookie

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I have a client app that using javascript to set cookie for URL: http://localhost/login

The code looks like this:

```
var c = "_s=" + sessionId + ";path='/';max-age=36000";
document.cookie = c;
console.log("c", c);
console.log("Cookie", document.cookie);
```

In chrome, it prints out:

```
c _s=1b022d51-00c3-4a40-a105-35c638986354;path='/';max-age=36000
Cookie _s=1b022d51-00c3-4a40-a105-35c638986354
```

But in IE (11 or edge 17)

It prints out:

```
c _s=1b022d51-00c3-4a40-a105-35c638986354;path='/';max-age=36000
Cookie
```

I have enabled setting cookie option in the IE option.

Any idea why IE still doesn’t let it set the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out IE is picky about the single quotes I used around the path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set cookie like below will work in IE.

```html
document.cookie = "abc=somevalue; path=/";
console.log("Cookie" , document.cookie);
```